# Exhaustion of 'memory' CD8 T cells

Tags: immunology, immune-system, infection, hiv

I've been reading literature on the exhaustion of cytotoxic CD8 T cells. In many of the papers I read, the authors aim to delineate molecular mechanisms that differ between exhausted and memory phenotypes; one such review on this field is the [following](https://www.nature.com/articles/nri3862) from Prof. John Wherry's group.

But unfortunately, I could not find any paper that discusses the possibility of recalled memory cells being prone to exhaustion. If I'm not wrong, exhaustion markers like PD-L1, Tim-3, etc. are present on memory cells at lower levels than exhausted cells. But in response to antigenic stimulation (recall response), do such 'recalled' memory cells also start accumulating exhaustion markers like short-lived effector cells? Can someone help me out, please?